# How to write data with some type but export it as const

Tags: typescript, types, constants, typescript-typings, typing

I would like to write some object that implement some type for now `TestType`
but export it as read only const

```
type TestType = { someProperty: { childProperty: string } }

const obj1: TestType = { someProperty: { childProperty: 'my custom text' } } //  will works
const take1: typeof obj1['someProperty']['childProperty'] = '' // will except string

const obj2 = { someProperty: { childProperty: 'my custom text' } } as const
const take2: typeof obj2['someProperty']['childProperty'] = 'my custom text' // will except 'my custom text'
```

I want to get them both
the object will implement the type but will be export as const

```
const obj3 = ({ someProperty: { childProperty: 'my custom text' } } as TestType) as const // will casue type error
const take3: typeof obj2['someProperty']['childProperty'] = 'my custom text' // will except 'my custom text'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wE5pgw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site and so non-native speakers are, unfortunately, at a disadvantage. In cases of miscommunication like this, it is in your best interest to engage in good faith to make sure that others understand you.  I am presuming, from context, that you were saying "I don't see a resemblance/similarity between these two questions" or "I don't think this is a duplicate of that question".  Am I understanding correctly?  A simple "yes" or "no" would suffice.

Comment: Also: if @jsejcksn's answer is not acceptable to you, could you please [edit] the question to demonstrate?  Currently the question is indeed a duplicate of the other one, and will probably be closed as such, unless you edit this question to distinguish them.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an identity function which is already constrained by another type.

You'll still have to use an `as const` assertion on the input argument. This isn't very ergonomic, but it addresses your case:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQYQQZyhQxjDQBMBJcgMSQB48xDjSpE0APbMc-RAEpoIcFOXoAFFHAAOaFFACeAaTSKANInABrMHADuYAHxGAFAEoAXInoAVDtzS9+TFiTBQzcAEYAra7bmiAC8Roj2AN4AsABQiIjoUCAoSD6+IWFpANyxAL6xsUpy4WiEtorFwYgRiPhwALZoUrLyStY1EAAWMAA25M1yCorWLKQA5oi5kzkxsSLM7KiY2LalUOWVyOhYuARE7hTUdHZrG2hm5jNze4hpAIwhW8toq2UVaKY1dY0DrcPVyG6fV+Q2sAHJ6opkCBCA1ENhuGDJsiMPx5oRLgUYuj2FAMNo0HdrEU0HBgLc-HcANpg75NaSDJRggC6NK6vX6DL+LMeYIweignXktSI4yRAHoAFSxeKyxAAPUVitiZ0QYIARPy4ILhaMwGN1UiYPwBYhUfgYGMwBhvD00PC4PD3mr1ZDobD6vCuFBDQA6UwAJgAzAGA0FJeLYkA)

```ts
function createConstrainedIdFn <Constraint extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(): <T extends Constraint>(obj: T) => T {
  return obj => obj;
}

type TestType = { someProperty: { childProperty: string } };

const createTestType = createConstrainedIdFn<TestType>();

const obj1 = createTestType({ someProperty: { childProperty: 'my custom text' } } as const);

const take1: typeof obj1['someProperty']['childProperty'] = 'another string' /*
      ^^^^^
Type '"another string"' is not assignable to type '"my custom text"'.(2322) */
```

---

You can make the syntax a bit more concise by using a shorter function name and immediately invoking the returned function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=7&ssc=93&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJogPAYQQZygJwEMYwpEBTADynLBR0QCVyI58V0AFfOAB3PxQAngGlyQgDSJwAazBwA7mAB8ygBQBKAFwYAKhWq16ibGDxESUdXABGAKx26NiALzLE+gN4BYAFCJEfHIoEHwkWztXdwiAbj8AXz8-YX4PcjxdIVSXRE9EHDgAW3JuPgFhHTyIAAsYABsUUv5BIR1zEgBzRHjuuN8-VjMyCIBGV2QOXXSoTP51DTU8guKm8tbcxBr6xp5misQAckKhTZA8IsQaagPu28IGQbwNPoHcMihCGXIRnRTyOGAiFGAG0DssSrs1gcALqgrYNVYtGHjA6EeRQaoCfIETo3AD0ACo-AESYgAHoUil+WbkQ4AIjRcAxWPaYA6dJuMAY6MQ9xwMA6YEINjqtKgcEuWVpBzpx1O50KlyoUA5ADo1AAmADMGo1zgJeL8QA)

```ts
function id <Constraint extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(): <T extends Constraint>(obj: T) => T {
  return obj => obj;
}

type TestType = { someProperty: { childProperty: string } };

const obj1 = id<TestType>()({ someProperty: { childProperty: 'my custom text' } } as const);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is awesome, if you can think on any other way
please let me know,
I will prepare no use of function.
Because the real goal is more complex than that and function use will make it more difficult to implement

Comment: @MorBargig Yeah, TypeScript makes code more verbose in every scenario (but the benefits are usually worth it).

Comment: @jcalz Is there an open GH issue about partial genetic inference that (if a TS code change were implemented in response) would allow for this code to work with only a single function invocation, supplying only the constraint generic?